# Comparator for lower_bound for vector of pairs

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, c++17

I wanna make `lower_bound` for vector of pairs but I wanna use it only for first elements of pairs. I tried to make my own comparator like this:

```
bool find(const std::string& key) const {
        auto finder = std::lower_bound(words_.begin(), words_.end(), key,
                                       [](const std::string& key, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::iterator it)
                                       {return key != it->first;});
    }
```

but it doesn't work. How I should use comparator to compare only first elements of pairs?

Comment: That is completely the wrong signature for the comparator, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) indicates (element, value) also you're using the wrong comparison, same page says `binary predicate which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda is the wrong signature and comparison for `lower_bound()`. It is expected to compare a container element against the provided value. Which means it does not accept an `iterator` as input at all.

The 1st parameter of the lambda needs to accept the container element, and the 2nd parameter needs to accept the input value. So, you are probably looking for something more like this instead:

```
bool find(const std::string& key) const {
    auto finder = std::lower_bound(words_.begin(), words_.end(),
        key,
        [](const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &elem, const std::string &value) {
            return elem.first < value;
        }
    );
    ...
}
```

That being said, if all you are trying to do is find an exact match to the specified `key`, [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) would make more sense:

```
bool find(const std::string& key) const {
    auto finder = std::find_if(words_.begin(), words_.end(),
        [&key](const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &elem) {
            return elem.first == key;
        }
    );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lower_bound` function (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)) defines the comparator (aka the predicate) as taking in two values to compare (in your case, two const std::string &). Change your predicate from accepting a `const std::string &` and an iterator:

`[](const std::string& key, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::iterator it) {...}`

to a lambda accepting two `const std::string &`:

`[](const std::string& first, const std::string &second) {...}`

Comment: I'm fairly certain at least one (probably both) of these arguments is supposed to be a pair...